# Long Tasks That Reduce Lighthouse Scores?

Tags: javascript, performance, web-applications, lighthouse, page-load-time

I'm working on improving the Lighthouse score for my web app. I've done a solid job of lazy-loading components. Now I have to figure out what to do about these long-running tasks. I've read various articles about how to fix it, but they are very generic and general, and I haven't yet figured out how to apply them to my app.

The most recent SO posts seem to be about a couple years old or so, so it may be time to raise the topic again.

Here's an example Performance chart of a long-running task in my app:

[image]

I have no idea what to do with this yet. I know I can't ask here for open-ended advice. But does someone have the URL of an article I may have missed, that could tell me what to do next?